How to descending order Maximum aggregated value at the top minimum aggregated value at the bottom in the chart like the image
To render the chart using Dimple.js, ensure the maximum aggregated value appears at the top of the chart and the minimum aggregated value at the bottom.
Current output:
While rendering the chart using Dimple.js, the maximum aggregated value appears at the bottom of the chart and the minimum aggregated value appears at the top. Find the image here (https://i.sstatic.net/AEpM5u8J.png)
Requirement:
The top aggregated value should appear at the top, and the minimum value should appear at the bottom. See the desired output here. (https://i.sstatic.net/pBjYD47f.png)
There is any option available for change order (ascending and descending )
